# Subscribing and publishing geometry/Twist messages from Turtlesim

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros

I'm working on an exercise that uses the Turtlesim tool.

I have to create a node vel_filter that subscribes to messages published by the pubvel node (from the book A Gentle Introduction to Ros by O'Kane) and immediately republish only those messages who have positive angular velocity.

The pubvel code is given below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_velocity");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/cmd_vel", 1000);

srand(time(0));

ros::Rate rate(2);
while(ros::ok()){
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
msg.linear.x = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);
msg.angular.z = 2*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) - 1;

pub.publish(msg);

ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);

rate.sleep();
}
}
```

This publishes random linear and angular movements messages of type geometry/Twist on the turtle1/cmd_vel topic. Now I want to create a node vel_filter, subscribe on this topic to receive those messages, and publish only the messages with positive angular velocity on a different topic. (I'm not sure on which topic I should publish this).

What I have written so far for the vel_filter node is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h>

void filterVelocityCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& msg){
if (msg.angular.z > 0){
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Subscriber velocities:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "filter_velocity");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turtle1/cmd_vel",1000,&filterVelocityCallback);
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/pose", 1000);

ros::Rate rate(2);

while(ros::ok()){
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

pub.publish(msg);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Filtered velocities:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);

rate.sleep();
}

ros:

:spin();
}
```

But this gives me the following:

```
[ INFO] [1492674948.750695494]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
[ INFO] [1492674949.250756910]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
[ INFO] [1492674949.750739740]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
[ INFO] [1492674950.250739795]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
[ INFO] [1492674950.750736997]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
[ INFO] [1492674951.250766297]: Filtered velocities: linear=0 angular=0
```

Note that I didn't apply the filter yet. I used the turtle1/pose topic to publish (I have my doubts if this is correct). If I only apply the subscriber it works fine, but when I add the publisher it doesn't reach the callback function anymore.

My CMakeLists looks like this (don't bother about the vel_printer):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(me41025_33)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs turtlesim)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_pubvel pubvel.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_printer vel_printer.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_filter vel_filter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_pubvel ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_printer ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_filter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_pubvel PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME pubvel PREFIX "")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_printer PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME vel_printer PREFIX "")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_vel_filter PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME vel_filter PREFIX "")
```

And my package.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
<name>me41025_33</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The agitr package</description>

<maintainer email="stijn@todo.todo">stijn</maintainer>

<license>TODO</license>

    <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
    <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>

<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<build_depend>turtlesim</build_depend>
<run_depend>turtlesim</run_depend>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

</package>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your post contains some irrelevant stuff , `vel_printer` for an example and some errors like linebreaks between `ros::spin();`. To get people interested in your post, you should avoid these. Always a [MCVE] should be posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ros::spin()` here. You need `ros::spinOnce();` inside the `while` loop. Read the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) for explanation.

Also note that you called `pubvel` and `vel_filter` to be nodes in your post. These are not nodes. `publish_velocity` and `filter_velocity` respectively are the nodes here.

Furthermore, it would be better if you don't apply the conditions in the callback function and do that inside the `while` loop of the main function.

Sp your fixed `vel_filter.cpp` file will be this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h>

float linx, angZ;

void filterVelocityCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& msg){
   //Using the callback function just for subscribing  
   //Subscribing the message and storing it in 'linx' and 'angZ'
   linx = msg.linear.x;      angZ = msg.angular.z;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "filter_velocity");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turtle1/cmd_vel",1000,&filterVelocityCallback);
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/pose", 1000);
  ros::Rate rate(2);

  while(ros::ok()){
     geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
     msg.linear.x = linx;     msg.angular.z = angZ;

     //It would be better to apply the conditions within the main function and use the 
     //Callback function just for subscribing
     if (angZ > 0){
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Subscriber velocities:"<<" linear="<<linx<<" angular="<<angZ);
        //The above line doesn't publish. It's like printf (but not exactly)
        pub.publish(msg);   //This line is for publishing. It publishes to 'turtle1/pose'
     }  
     rate.sleep();
     ros::spinOnce();      //Notice this
  } 
}
```

---

**Recommended reading:**

1. [Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).
2. [Writing a Publisher and a Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).